# My loss function starts to diverge in Tensorflow1. What can I do?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

First of all I am new with DNN network. I am training a network using tensorflow 1. I used TF1 since I used a paper as benchmark of my code and it is written in TF1, although I tried to implement the same algorithm in TF2 I could not achieve the same performance that I achieved with the original version.

My problem is normally my loss function, which is the MSE, goes down however after a random number of epochs the loss function diverges to NaN. It is really strange since although the result diverges, If I train the network again with the last set of weights previous to divergence. The loss MSE continues to reduce until new divergence happens.

I read this type of error is related with numerical inestability. In the algorithm I am implementing, the network is feed several times before compute the loss function, with the network output is computed a new input which is used to feed again the network. The process is repeated several times and after that the loss function is computed. It is similar to the following code (I have simplified the code since it is quite long)

```
input = ...
for t in range(max_iter):
        x1 = tf.nn.relu(input@A1+b1)
        x1 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
        x2 = tf.nn.relu(x1@A2+b2)
        x2 = BatchNormalization()(x2)
        x3 = tf.nn.relu(x2@A3+b3)
        x3 = BatchNormalization()(x3)
        output = x3@A4+b4
        input = recompute_input(output)
compute_loss(input, true_values)
```

I suppose during this process some inputs of the network break the gradients, I have read and tryed the following solutions:

1. Standarize the network input
2. Changing the learning rate
3. Changing the number of batches

I have implemented all the previous solution but I have not solved the problem. Currently I am using Adam Optimizer with learning rage equal to 0.0001 and I keep having the same problem, randomly the algorithm diverges. I tried changing learning rate but it ends in divergence again so I do not how I should do.

How do you recommend me to proceed? In any case, there is some way to check the values of the tensors inside the "run" in order to analyze when the result diverges?

Thank you in advance!